# Entity Framework can't find my connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, connection-string

Just calling my WCF to populate my datagridView

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReferenceReservations.ReservationsServiceClient srr = 
               new ServiceReferenceReservations.ReservationsServiceClient();
                        gridData.DataSource = srr.getAllReservations();
}
```

and this what mycf does transforming return type of the businesslayer to have the right one

```
public List<clsReservation> getAllReservations()
{
    List<clsReservation> oDataList = new List<clsReservation>().ToList();

    List<Reservation> mesReservations = BusinessLayer.Reservations.LoadAllReservationsEF();

    foreach (var item in mesReservations)
    {
        clsReservation cls = new clsReservation()
                {
                    id = item.id,
                    lecteurID = item.lecteurID,
                    livreID=item.livreID
                };
        oDataList.Add(cls);
    }

    return oDataList;
}
```

and the business layer is going to call the data access layer and returning back with data

```
return DataAccessLayer.Reservations.LoadAllReservationEF();
```

Then my data access layer is using Entity Framework

```
public static List<Reservation> LoadAllReservationEF()
{
    List<Reservation> malisteReservation = new List<Reservation>();

    using (bibliothequeEntities dbcontext = new bibliothequeEntities())
    {
        List<Reservation_SelectAll_Result> maliste = dbcontext.Reservation_SelectAll().ToList();

        var x = from p in maliste
                select new Reservation
                        {
                            id = p.id,
                            lecteurID = p.lecteurID,
                            livreID = p.livreID,
                        };

        foreach (var item in x)
        {
            malisteReservation.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return malisteReservation;
}
```

My data access layer is throwing an error in Model1.Context.cs:

> No connection string named 'bibliothequeEntities' could be found in the application config file of the DAL

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="bibliothequeEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=arpa;initial catalog=bibliotheque;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But I have that connectionstring in my DAL and also in the startup project calling the WCF. I've already tried to comment the method "onModelCreating" to avoid the throw error but still can't find a solution

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the constructor (just the declaration and any `base` call) for `bibliothequeEntities`

Comment: public bibliothequeEntities()
            : base("name=bibliothequeEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
         //   throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

Comment: Is the .config file you refer to definitely the _main application's_ config file, not the one for the assembly that `bibliothequeEntities` is in, if it is different?

Comment: i've got 6 projects

Comment: i've got 6 projects the GUI, WCF LIbrary, BAL, DAL and the model is in the DAL but as you can see the GUI can only access the others library by wcf

Comment: What is hosting the WCF library; IIS?

Comment: i guess,it's a simply wcf llibrary with several wcf inside

Comment: i thnk it's self hosted

Answer (score 0):

If hosting in IIS, you need to copy the contents of your app.config file into the web.config file of the virtual directory where you're hosting it in IIS.  I don't believe this is done automatically for you.

If you use something else to host, you similarly need to locate the folder where the host is executing, and copy the contents into *that* app/web.config.

In short, you the connection-strings need to be in the .config of the *host*, not any other assembly.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924405(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: it's just aself hosted ,i didn'i configure IIs or anything else it's a simply wcf with winforms as client

Comment: public virtual ObjectResult<Reservation_SelectAll_Result> Reservation_SelectAll()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Reservation_SelectAll_Result>("Reservation_SelectAll");
        }

Comment: this is the method throwing the error it' generated by entitframework

Comment: You will need to find out more about how you're hosting the WCF Library before you can figure out where to copy your .config settings to.  If you're just running from Visual Studio, it will probably host in the WCF Service Host, but that's just a Visual Studio helper and not intended for production use.  There is a lot of information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158(v=vs.110).aspx), including reasons why you'd choose each option.

Comment: i think my really problem has a link with entity not installed on other layers it was just installed in DAL

Answer (score 0):

the connection string should be in wcf that's all there is no need to even put it in dataccesslayer